# VBS + cant create VBS script type on windows XP

Tags: vbscript

I work with windows XP operation system

When I create new vbs file on my desktop as VBscript.vbs
The file still defined as .txt file and not as .vbs file

From properties I see also type is a txt file

What need to do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you installed and enabled WindowsScriptingHost?

Comment: Windows Scripting Host is installed by default with Windows XP. You'd have to have either manually removed it, or used a custom installer CD. If you have the know-how to do that, you'd know how to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you will find that your filename is actually "filename.vbs.txt".

The file extension ".txt" was probably automatically added by your text editor.

Try cutting and pasting your code into a new file in your text editor and then use "Save As" instead of "Save".

Ensuring that you type in the full file name including the .vbs extension and select "All File Types" if you have a dropdown to select one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of upvotes, but this is the correct answer. You might want to go to Control Panel -> Folder Options, and disable "Hide file extensions for known file types" (or something like that).